# How to wait for a file to download in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How can I check if a give file is already downloaded before processing it?

I have successfully created a Chrome Webdriver instance with a different default download folder with the following code:

```
Path currentWorkingDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory",
          System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "DownloadedTickets");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currentWorkingDir + "\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver ticketWebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But when I try to access the file without waiting for it download I get NullPointerExceptions.

How can I check if the file exists in a folder before accessing it?

Comment: You could just try to open it every x seconds until you don't get the NPE anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom expected condition:

```
public ExpectedCondition<Boolean> filepresent() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            File f = new File("D:\\program.txt"); 
            return f.exists();
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
          return String.format("file to be present within the time specified");
        }
    };
}
```

Here we are checking that a specific file called program.txt is present. you can change it a argument passed to the expected condition where thr value is the expected downloaded file

and use it as :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    wait.until(pageobject.filepresent());
```